# How would I create a Custom Register Segue on Xamarin.Mac?

Tags: macos, xamarin, xamarin.mac

I have a program where I want the user to be able to register for an account. The main view controller has a **register** button that they can click. I want the window to be replaced, instead of sheet or modal segues. Then, when they click **done**, they will be redirected back to the main view controller.

Answer (score 0):

You can use follow way to navigate to another window :

```
ButtonClickEvent.Activated += (sender, e) => {
      Console.WriteLine("Button Click");

      NSWindow newWindow = new NSWindow();
      newWindow.Title = "Second Window";
      newWindow.SetFrame(new CGRect(500, 500, 300, 200),true);
      // set be key window and be front
      newWindow.MakeKeyAndOrderFront(null);
      // close current window
      View.Window.OrderOut(Self);
};
```

And when back to previous , also can use this way .

============================Update==================================

I will share an screenshot to explain that as follow :

[image]

You will see there are two WindowControllers and two ViewControllers .

- First Window Controller (MainWindow) -> First View Controller (ViewController)
- Second Window Controller (SecondWindow) -> Second View Controller (SecondViewController)

**First View Controller** :

```
ButtonClickEvent.Activated += (sender, e) => {
      Console.WriteLine("Button Push");

      var storyboard = NSStoryboard.FromName ("Main", null);
      var controller = storyboard.InstantiateControllerWithIdentifier ("SecondWindow") as NSWindowController;
      // display
      controller.Window.MakeKeyAndOrderFront(null);
     // close current window
      View.Window.OrderOut(Self);
};
```

**Second View Controller** :

```
ButtonClickEvent.Activated += (sender, e) => {
      Console.WriteLine("Button Back");

      var storyboard = NSStoryboard.FromName ("Main", null);
      var controller = storyboard.InstantiateControllerWithIdentifier ("MainWindow") as NSWindowController;
      // display
      controller.Window.MakeKeyAndOrderFront(null);
     // close current window
      View.Window.OrderOut(Self);
};
```

The effect :

[image]

==================================Update===============================

Open **Main.storyboard** with **Xcode Interface Builder** :

[image]

Review whether **Storyboard ID** be setted in project :

[image]

Comment: I have information inside a ViewController that has its own class. How would I introduce this view controller into the window?

Comment: Also it doesn't make the window closable, how would I do that?

Comment: @GabeLevin If want to make previous page hide , you need to use `NSWindowController` to navigate . Therefore , here you can add second `ViewController` to second `WindowController` . Then navigating from Main window controller to secode window controller , press back button to Main window Contoller .I will update answer .

Comment: MakeKeyAndOrderFront is for NSWindow so it doesn’t work.

Comment: @GabeLevin Sorry , forgot the `Window` when editting answer , the right code as follow `controller.Window.MakeKeyAndOrderFront(null);` You also can use `controller.ShowWindow(this)` .

Comment: @GabeLevin Have a check whether controller can be get content first .

Comment: @GabeLevin Here is my sample project link , you can have a look to check where problem is . https://www.dropbox.com/s/qv3qg0t543s6a9y/XamarinMacNavigation.zip?dl=0

Comment: I copied your code word for word, and it still didn't work, but your program did.

Comment: @GabeLevin You should be sure that `StoryBoard` has defined the controller , then code will get the controller .

Comment: @GabeLevin I have updated answer , you can have a look when you have time . In addition , you also  can share a sample project link here , I will check that in local site .